# Django Model Field as Button Group

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-widget

How can i create a **button group** using Django model fields and widgets?

```
#models.py

GENDER_CHOICES = (
   ('M', 'Male'),
   ('F', 'Female'),
   ('-', 'Other')
)

class Profile(models.Model):
     gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=128)
```

This field is rendering as a Select field, a *dropdown*, but i need a button group, just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKVb5.png).